# Get html object in controller through ajax

Tags: java, jquery

I have a Html object(var table) in my jsp page, and i want to send to controller through ajax to write it in a text file. But once i send an object its giving me null pointer exception

```
var table =$(tabledata);

$.ajax({
      url: "htmlToExel.do",
      type : "POST",
      data : table,
      success: function(){

      },
      error: function(){

      }
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/

Comment: @user2894607, what is `table` here ?

Comment: table containing html table data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POST send text. You want to send HTML object.

If you want send HTML code, you try:

```
<div class="table">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<script>
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'url',
        data: {
            table: $('div.table').html()
        }
    }).done(function(result){
        console.log('ok');
    });
</script>
```

But if you want to send data from a table, you must first serialize them.